# Motion Layout is not Animating

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, animation, android-motionlayout

I am trying to use motion Layout for the first time and the animation is just not working.
the sizes are changing according to set values but they are happening instantaneously and no motion or animation is visible.
I have attached my activity_main and layout_scene layout files below.

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="MG 2256 142"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_shape"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/truck_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/TextViewFrom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleX="2"
        android:scaleY="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_airport_shuttle_24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewFrom"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fromtv"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/fromtv"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="America, Houston"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typetv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TextViewFrom"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/fromtv"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="Type"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TransitTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/typetv"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/TextViewFrom"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="Transit"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fromtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="from"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
        android:text="To"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewTo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/totv"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/totv"
        android:text="Canada, Toronto"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statustv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/totv"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/typetv"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/departureTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/statustv"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/TransitTextView"
        android:text="Departure"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weigthtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/typetv"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/statustv"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/typetv"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textColor="#D6D6D6"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/weigthtv"
        android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
        android:text="890g"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/truck_iv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="6 days"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/trackRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:listitem="@tools:sample/cities"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/space"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Acitivity_main_scene.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">

        <OnSwipe motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/trackRecyclerView"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top"/>

       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            motion:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
        <Constraint
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/title" />


    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            motion:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
        <Constraint
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/title" />


    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Also the drag direction is also working in the opposite direction I don't know why.
The animations are working perfectly when viewing in the android studio transition animation window, but when using in a real device, no animations.
Please let me know if there's any error in my code.